# Wait for message then send response discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I'm looking for some help with the following code:

```
if message.content.startswith("keycode"):
      channel = bot.get_channel(00000000000000)
      await channel.send('sentence 1')
      await asyncio.sleep(3)
      await channel.send('sentence 2.')
      await asyncio.sleep(3)
      await channel.send('Please reply "yes" or "no".')

      try:
        await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0)
      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await channel.send('You ran out of time to answer!')
      if message.content == 'yes':
        await channel.send('You replied yes')
      else:
        await channel.send('You didn't reply yes.')
```

Basically upon request, the discord bot will give out a response to the selected channel and then following that response it will ask if a user can reply "yes" or "no". Then, if the a user replies "yes" it will give out the "You replied yes" response and if not it will give out the "You didn't reply yes" response.

My issue is that whenever I run the command and type "yes" after its response, I always get the "You didn't reply yes" response". (It does send the "you ran out of time to answer" response if I don't respond within the given time frame).

I'm very new to all this so it would be great if someone could pick up on all my errors. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you are currently comparing the *first* message's content for 'yes' rather than the one you waited for.  In other words, if that first message (the one that starts with 'keycode') does not equal yes exactly (it never will since it starts with 'keycode'), you'll never send your yes reply

Instead, use the returned message event from [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), which will give you the *new* message that you waited for to introspect:

```py
if message.content.startswith("keycode"):
    channel = bot.get_channel(00000000000000)
    await channel.send('sentence 1')
    ...

    try:
        reply_message = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await channel.send('You ran out of time to answer!')
    else:
        if reply_message.content == 'yes':
            await channel.send('You replied yes')
        else:
            await channel.send('You didn\'t reply yes.')
```

Answer (score 2):

I see what your trying to do. I would make another `if message.content == "no":` So something like..

```py
if message.content.startswith("keycode"):
      await message.channel.send('sentence 1')
      await asyncio.sleep(3)
      await message.channel.send('sentence 2.')
      await asyncio.sleep(3)
      await message.channel.send('Please reply "yes" or "no".')

      try:
        await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0)
      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.channel.send('You ran out of time to answer!')
      if message.content == 'yes':
        await message.channel.send('You replied yes')
      if message.content == 'no':
        await message.channel.send('You replied no')
      else:
        await message.channel.send("You didn't reply with yes or no.")
```

Also I see you want your messages to be send to a certain channel seeing `channel = bot.get_channel(00000000000000)`. If someone sends "keycode" in a different channel then that one, then the bot won't send it to the channel the author typed "keycode" if that makes since. So I changed the code in order to make the bot send these messages in the same channel the author typed in.